# extracting multiple columns with different separators and positions

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

Experts,

I have a question. I have a big data file with multiple columns and rows. The first couple of columns are separated by a tab delimiter and the second part is separated by a ";". I would like to extract the first five columns. And from the ";" separated part the EUR_AF= column and the AF= and place this in a new file.

Example of file (2 rows):

```
13  19020013    rs181615907 C   T   100 PASS    AA=.;AC=83;AF=0.12;AFR_AF=0.05;AMR_AF=0.15;AN=758;ASN_AF=0.17;AVGPOST=0.8701;ERATE=0.0007;EUR_AF=0.11;LDAF=0.1423;RSQ=0.6009;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;THETA=0.0051;VT=SNP   
13  19020047    rs186129910 A   .   100 PASS    AA=.;AC=0;AF=0.0005;AFR_AF=0.0020;AN=758;AVGPOST=0.9992;ERATE=0.0005;LDAF=0.0008;RSQ=0.4992;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;THETA=0.0112;VT=SNP
13  19020095    rs140871821 C   T   100 PASS    AA=.;AC=38;AF=0.05;AFR_AF=0.08;AMR_AF=0.05;AN=758;ASN_AF=0.03;AVGPOST=0.9904;ERATE=0.0005;EUR_AF=0.05;LDAF=0.0538;RSQ=0.9245;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;THETA=0.0069;VT=SNP
```

I tried this:

```
awk -F'[\t;]' ' NR > 30 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /EUR_AF/) {
        printf $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $10 " " "%s ", $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}' head50.txt
```

output:

```
13 19020013 rs181615907 C T AF=0.12 EUR_AF=0.11 

13 19020095 rs140871821 C T AF=0.05 EUR_AF=0.05 
13 19020145 rs57048904 G T AF=0.61 EUR_AF=0.73 
13 19020341 rs184229798 C T AF=0.03 EUR_AF=0.09 
13 19020627 rs12018140 A G AF=0.70 EUR_AF=0.71
```

Problem:
Now there are lines missing (second one) where the EUR_AF part isn't filled in. I would like to see these lines as well with the AF= parameter in there see below:

```
13 19020013 rs181615907 C T AF=0.12 EUR_AF=0.11 
13 19020047 rs186129910 A . AF=0.0005
13 19020095 rs140871821 C T AF=0.05 EUR_AF=0.05 
13 19020145 rs57048904 G T AF=0.61 EUR_AF=0.73 
13 19020341 rs184229798 C T AF=0.03 EUR_AF=0.09 
13 19020627 rs12018140 A G AF=0.70 EUR_AF=0.71
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Ruben

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smart way to get what you want:

```
awk '{split($8,a,";AF=");split($8,b,";EUR_AF=");print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"AF="a[2]+0,"EUR_AF="b[2]+0}' file
13 19020013 rs181615907 C T AF=0.12 EUR_AF=0.11
13 19020047 rs186129910 A . AF=0.0005 EUR_AF=0
13 19020095 rs140871821 C T AF=0.05 EUR_AF=0.05
```

It will print `EUR_AF=0` for line `2`, since it does not exists.

If you do not like it printed at all, you can test for it:

```
awk '{split($8,a,";AF=");split($8,b,";EUR_AF=");print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"AF="a[2]+0,(b[2]?"EUR_AF="b[2]+0:"")}' file
13 19020013 rs181615907 C T AF=0.12 EUR_AF=0.11
13 19020047 rs186129910 A . AF=0.0005
13 19020095 rs140871821 C T AF=0.05 EUR_AF=0.05
```